# How to draw protein secondary structure icons

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I was trying to get a figure like Figure A in this [link](http://gooa.las.ac.cn/external/imgshow/m3139003). The only thing that I couldn't succeed is icons on the top of Figure A in the link. I don't know how to get those icons (alpha helix, beta sheet and coil). The input file I used is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sikpv6kv7e8vhi2/rmsf.xvg?dl=0). The first column (x-axis of figure) of the input file is residue numbers. Icons represent the residues. For instance,  residues 1-25 , residues 26-45,  residues 46-60 and residues 61-80 represent alpha helix, beta sheet, coil and alpha helix, respectively... My code gives me the below figure. As I said, I also need to add protein secondary structure icons on the top of the figure. How can I do that?

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pylab as plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy, scipy, pylab, random
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


with open("rmsf.xvg", "r") as f:
    x=[]
    y1=[]
    y2=[]
    y3=[]
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'): continue
        row = line.split()
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y1.append(float(row[1]))
        y2.append(float(row[2]))
        y3.append(float(row[3]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.2,2.2), dpi=300)
ax = plt.subplot(111)


plt.xlim(0, 210)
plt.ylim(0, 0.7)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(7))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.02))

plt.plot(x, y1, 'k', label='A',  linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'b', label='B',  linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(x, y3, 'g', label='C',  linewidth=0.5)

plt.legend( loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=0, borderaxespad=0., prop={'size':7})

plt.xlabel('# residue', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('RMSF (nm)', fontsize=10)

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
  ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.14)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.96)


plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=0)


plt.savefig("rmsf.png", dpi=300)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: matplotlib does not have a function for it. You probably won't find a simple way to do that.